# Bought a new laptop and tried installing Angular but keep getting error asking to run as admin?

Tags: javascript, angular, command-prompt

I keep getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat \'C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lstat',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-12T22_05_01_741Z-debug.log
```

I have ran command prompt as admin and tried npm cache clean but haven't had any luck. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: what is the command you tried ? and are you  a admin privelaged user?

Comment: i used npm install -g @angular/cli and yes I checked and I am the local admin.

Comment: `local admin` means?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the Command Prompt as administrator

Navigate to C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, right click, and select "Run As Administrator", and try running the npm commands in that cmd window.

Comment: what npm version are you on? seems to be an issue with later npm packages + windows = boom...
https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/issues/304

Comment: downloaded and tried to install on 8.9.3 LTS but still doesn't work.